# Cannot assign value of type (aka 'Array<Dictionary<String, Style>>') to (aka 'Dictionary<String, Style>')

Tags: javascript, swift, dictionary

This is my code:

```
override func style(node: Node) throws -> StyleNode {
    guard let objectNode = try super.style(node: node) as? StyleNode
    else {
      throw UEErrors.unrecoverableError(message: "Could not create Node")
    }

    guard let stylesArray = node.stylesMap else {
      throw UEErrors.unrecoverableError(message: "stylesMap is missing")
    }
    objectNode.stylesMap = stylesArray //error : Cannot assign value of type '[[StyleID : Style]]' (aka 'Array<Dictionary<String, Style>>') to type '[StyleID : Style]' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Style>')
    return objectNode
  }
```

Note: `var stylesMap: [[StyleID: Style]]?`
How do I create a dictionary of `stylesArray`? (I think Map in javascript is dictionary in swift)

I'm, trying to port javascript code to swift. Below is javascript code:

```
static style(
    node: Node,
    baseProps: BaseConstructorProperties,
  ): this {
    const stylesArray = assertNonNull(
      Node?.stylesMap,
      'stylesMap is missing',
    );

    return new this({
      ...baseProps,
      stylesMap: new Map(stylesArray),
    });
  }
```

Comment: You currently have an array of `[StyleID : Style]` that you're trying to set to a property that accepts a single value of that type. Presumably, you need to decide which item you want. The first one?

Comment: @jnpdx yes the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the first item, as mentioned in the comments, you can replace the following line:

```
objectNode.stylesMap = stylesArray
```

with:

```
guard let first = stylesArray.first else {
  throw UEErrors.unrecoverableError(message: "No items")
}
objectNode.stylesMap = first
```

Comment: If i want to return the second, i should be using stylesArray.last?

Comment: If it only had two items, yes. Or `stylesArray[1]` (make sure to check that you're not beyond the length of the array first -- accessing by subscript will crash if you are beyond the array length)

Comment: What if i want to return a dictonary?

Comment: `[StyleID : Style]` *is* a dictionary